# Counting antichains in the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: combinatorics

By the Dedekind number function, let us mean the function $M : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ given by asserting that $M(n)$ is the number of antichains present in $\mathcal{P}(X)$, where $X$ is an arbitrary set of cardinality $n$. It follows that
$$2^n < M(n) < 2^{2^n},$$
for all $n \geq 1$.

> **Q.** Do either of the real numbers
>
> $$\lambda_0 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2^n}{M(n)} \qquad \lambda_1 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{M(n)}{2^{2^n}}$$
>
> differ from zero?
>
> - If so, is there known an explicit expression for this number?
> - If not, what is its approximate value?

I feel like $\lambda_0$ probably equals $0$, so I'm more interested in $\lambda_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OEIS sequence [A000372](http://oeis.org/A000372) and references there.  In particular, it says that the asymptotics of $M(n)$ are stated in 
A. D. Korshunov, The number of monotone Boolean functions, Problemy Kibernet. No. 38, (1981), 5-108, 272. MR0640855 (83h:06013) (which I have not looked at).

EDIT: the link http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath094.htm quotes Korshunov's result for even $n$ as:

$$M(n) \sim 2^{C(n)} \exp \left( c(n) \left( 2^{-n/2} + n^2 2^{-n-5} - n 2^{-n-4}\right)\right) $$

where $C(n)$ is the middle binomial coefficient ${n \choose n/2}$ and $c(n)$ the neighbouring coefficient ${n \choose 1+n/2}$.
Now I get $$\eqalign{C(n) &\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi n}} 2^n\cr c(n) 2^{-n/2} &\approx \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{n\pi}} 2^{n/2}}$$

which leads to $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$.